# How to calculate gradient for vector function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, gradient-descent

I just want to calculate the gradient of $$f(x)=\frac{||Ax-b||_2^2}{c^Tx+d}$$ where $x,b\in R^n,A\in R^{n\times n},c,d\in R$.

I guess the value should be like
$$\nabla f(x)=(2A^T(Ax-b)(c^Tx+d)-c||Ax-b||_2^2)/(c^Tx+d)^2$$
By viewing x as scalar and do the calculation, and finally consider about the dimension of each variable. However, I want to know how exactly to do this.

I also notice a lot of rules for scalar has a analogous form for vector also. Is there a formula list for this or a conclusion/theorem about this? It would be awesome if someone can share me this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, define some new variables
$$\eqalign{
 y &= Ax-b &\ \ \  dy = A\,dx \cr
 T &= y:y &\ \ \  dT = 2y:dy \cr
 B &= c:x +d &\ \ \  dB = c:dx \cr
}$$
where colons denote the [Frobenius Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product).

Now write the function in terms of these variables, then find its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \frac{T}{B} \cr\cr
df &= \frac{BdT-TdB}{B^2} \cr
   &= \frac{B(2y:dy)-T(c:dx)}{B^2} \cr
   &= \frac{B(2y:A\,dx)-T(c:dx)}{B^2} \cr
   &= \frac{B(2A^Ty:dx)-T(c:dx)}{B^2} \cr
   &= \frac{B(2A^Ty)-T(c)}{B^2} \,:dx \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= \frac{B(2A^Ty)-T(c)}{B^2} \cr
}$$
The Frobenius, Hadamard, Kronecker, and ordinary matrix product follow a very simple rule for the differential of a product $$d(A\star B)=dA\star B+A\star dB$$ Further, the Frobenius and Hadamard products are commutative so terms can be re-arranged and combined much like scalar quantities, e.g. $$d(A\star A)= 2A\star dA$$

Answer (score 0):

The derivative, assuming it exists, can always be calculated in the original way: by computing the difference quotient. There's a subtlety here related to whether or not the function is differentiable (e.g. existence of partial derivatives does not quite suffice), but anywhere the function is differentiable you can compute:

$$
Df(x)v = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{ f(x + hv) - f(x)}{h},
$$
where $v$ is the direction the derivative is taken in. Therefore, to compute each entry of the matrix form of $Df(x)$, which is often referred to as the gradient, you explicitly compute the directional derivative by taking the limit.

Treating $x$ as a scalar variable, unfortunately, doesn't always work, because in the matrix setting multiplication does not commute.

As an example, I can show you how to differentiate $g(x) = \|Ax - b\|_2^2$. We compute

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{h}(g(x + hv) - g(x)) & = \frac{1}{h} \left( hv^T A^T A x + hx^T A^T A v - hv^T A^T b - h b^T A v + o(h) \right) \\
& = v^T A^T A x + x^T A^T A v - v^T A^T b - b^T A v + o(1) 
\end{align}

Since $g(x)$ is scalar, then each term is equal to its transpose, so this simplifies to
$$
2 x^T A^T Av - 2b^T Av + o(1).
$$
This is the derivative of $g$ evaluated at $v$, and hence as a matrix its derivative is $x^T A^T A - 2b^T A$. Sometimes the gradient refers to the transpose of this quantity, but that's a notational nightmare that I hope dies off in the future.

Some important tricks for computing derivatives more quickly can be generalized from the usual tricks for scalar derivatives. For the following I use the following notation:

$$
D[f](x)v
$$
Means the derivative (gradient) of $f$ at the point $x$, evaluated on the vector $v$. So there are three variables in the expression.

**The Product Rule**

Let $f,g$ be differentiable vector functions, and let $B(\cdot, \cdot)$ be a bilinear function. Then
$$
D[B(f, g)](x)v = B(D[f](x)v, g(x)) + B(f(x), D[g](x)v).
$$

**The Quotient Rule**

Let $f(x) = x^{-1}$, where $x$ is an element of a unital Banach algebra (more concretely, just take $x$ to be a square invertible matrix). Then

$$
D[f](x)v = -x^{-1} v x^{-1}.
$$
Note the order of multiplication here, as matrices (and Banach algebras in general) may not have commutative multiplication.

**Chain Rule**

Let $f: U \rightarrow V, g: V \rightarrow Z$, where $U \subset X, V \subset Y$, and $X,Y,Z$ are all Banach (vector) spaces. If $f$ is differentiable at $x \in U$ and $g$ is differentiable at $f(x)$, then $g \circ f$ is differentiable at $x$ and

$$
D[g \circ f](x) v = D[g](f(x)) D[f](x)v.
$$

Note that $D[f](x)v$ is a vector in $Y$, which works out because $D[g](f(x))$ is a linear map from $Y$ to $Z$.

Comment: This is absolutely correct, but I guess that part of the purpose of this question is to find out those rules that are similar to taking derivative of scalar. Yes vectors doesn't commute, but are there some rules which will make our life convenient so that we don't have to go back to definition every time we calculate this for every function?

Comment: Sure, I can append some additional information.